# Control Joints in Gazebo 1.4 not working

Tags: control, gazebo-1.4

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

I installed gazebo 1.4 on my machine just yesterday and have been trying out the tutorials. In the last part of the Mobile Robot example the tutorial mentions the Control Joints option on right clicking the model. I'm not getting the option as mentioned. I'm just getting Move To, Delete and View. Is there something else that I need to install or do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1251/control-joints-in-gazebo-1.4-not-working/) by [siddharth950](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/195/siddharth950/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There should be three very small white rectangles to the right of the 3D view. Those indicate you can grab that part with the mouse and slide open the Joints tab this way (grab + slide to the left).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2